# Benchmark simulating "realistic" desktop/server workload

Tags: linux, desktop, benchmarking

I'm currently working on a good energy estimation using the CPU's performance counters. To be able to choose the best counters, I need a benchmark simulating realistic workload.

So, does anybody know a good (free if possible) benchmark suite which simulates usual desktop and/or server workload?

I'm thinking of a suite of isolated benchmarks, e.g.

- compile C code
- interpretation of JavaScript
- some SSL
- some IO (disk/network usage)
- image conversion
- some math problem solving

In fact a good mix of tasks a computer executes all the time a user is working :-).

*EDIT*: The best would be something where very little floating point gets used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Phoronix Test Suite is your answer!
It can even use external wat-o-meter.
And is best benchmark of cpu and gpu for linux.

Comment: przemo_li, I found phoronix, too, some days ago :-). In the beginning I was very happy with it, but some tests use way to much floating point operations. Do you know if there's something like a integer test suite in phoronix? Actually I use SPEC CPU2006 INT suite which I could find on some university server ;-)

Comment: I do not use PTS. But you can always call(email) author.

Answer (score 1):

The best benchmark would probably be installing Apache or some other web server, setting up a script on one or more computers to request pages (using http, https, and whatever other protocols you will use). You could make a script to request from localhost, but it would be more realistic if you had an external computer making requests, you could also test network latency.

Once set up, you could use PowerTop to estimate watts used during load.